# How to flatten MultiIndex by a method/expression in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to flatten a hierarchical MultiIndex to a flat Index

Theoretically, assigning to `df1.columns` does the jobs, however I wonder whether there is a method call using a lambda for doing that?! It would make nicer pipe programming.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(10,2)), columns=list("ab"))
df1 = (df
       .rolling(2)
       .agg(["min", "max"])
      )
df1.columns = df1.columns.map("{0[0]}_{0[1]}".format)
df1
```

Can I replace the columns in a method call with a lambda - hence inside the big parenthesis (but something nicer than a Python function with `pipe` though)?

Comment: I think examples of your data would go a long way.  If you just want the index as tupels you can do `pd.Index(my_multiindex)`

Comment: The above is basically a full working example. But instead of starting a separate assignment `df1.columns = ...`, I'd like to add a method call inside `d1 = (...)` to have a clean pipeline. The result is already what I want.

Comment: @Gerenuk, AFAIK currently it's not possible. It would be possible if `DataFrame.rename(columns=lambda x: print(x))` would operate with tuples for multi-level columns, but unfortunately it's not the case

Comment: @MaxU: Yes, that's what my experiments showed :/ Well, in doubt I can opt for the `.pipe()`, but I thought maybe I'm missing a command.

Comment: Updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.rolling(2).agg(["min", "max"]).T.apply(
    lambda x:
        x.append(pd.Series(dict(new='_'.join(x.name)))),
    1).set_index('new').rename_axis(None).T
```

[image]

Comment: I think we can't use `df1.columns` as it doesn't exist yet, if we are talking about  the "pipeline" (chained) approach...

Comment: @MaxU that's true

Comment: @MaxU tell me what you think of this.  It's still obnoxious in my opinion

Comment: yeah, this is it. But i'd think twice before using it with big DFs ;-)

Comment: I assume that's the best possible with current Pandas commands. Thanks! In that case I will probably consider using a proper function doing the columns assignment and use it with pipe.

Comment: @Gerenuk I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution with pandas 0.21.0+ using `set_axis` with `inplace=False`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(10,2)), columns=list("ab"))
df1 = (df
       .rolling(2)
       .agg(["min", "max"])
      ).pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis([x.columns.map('_'.join)], axis=1, inplace=False))
df1
```

Output:

```
      a_min     a_max     b_min     b_max
0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 -0.308058  0.234267 -1.470612  0.051591
2  0.234267  1.983296  0.051591  0.181318
3  1.729354  1.983296  0.181318  0.648528
4 -0.920250  1.729354  0.648528  0.982604
5 -1.588438 -0.920250  0.448492  0.982604
6 -1.588438 -0.388845 -1.751965  0.448492
7 -0.394825 -0.388845 -1.751965 -0.844420
8 -0.394825  0.657264 -0.844420 -0.000743
9  0.309141  0.657264 -0.067996 -0.000743
```